# save all data when logout (php-mysqli)

Tags: php, mysqli

is possible to processing three process.php in one statement on different page when logout?

```
modul/proccess1.php
modul/processs2.php
modul/processs3.php
```

all the pages process have value for saving data like this:

```
data1.php --> proccess1.php
data2.php --> proccess2.php
data3.php --> proccess3.php
```

how the pages can call in one statement to proccess them all?

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
session_destroy();


header("location:modul/proccess1.php");
header("location:modul/proccess2.php");
header("location:modul/proccess3.php");

?>
```

if i done like above code, it appear no data saved.

Cause it dont know what is to save

Comment: are you trying to save local data, like user input/js/html changes? give us some code, to not walking in the dark

Comment: second thing...the flow you describe there will not work. Only if you are trying something like: header: process1. In that file you have: header process2(in the end) and in process2 file you have header process3. Is a very bad practice because your code will not be reusable. You should think Object Oriented. You will have a file which require all 3 headers and: process1->proceed(); process2->proceed() so on.

Comment: so the solution, i must make a function to do all proccess?

Comment: or can you give me a simple code as your explained?

Comment: do you know how to work with classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. The propper way to do that is using oop, not procedural. You have to think more modulary, more reusable code. To make you an ideea how things should work: you define those 3 process1,2,3 as functions in a separate file called save.php (for example). Now, when a user is logging out, you will have a file: onlogout.php. That file will require save.php. All the functions defined there will now be available here, so you can call now process1,2,3(parameters like username and so on) and anytime you need to do at least one of those 3 processes, you require save.php. You have now only one file to modify if you want to change something. You will heve only one file defining reusable tasks. Define those functions using parameters. I think you are begginer, I am not pro, but that's how I can help you

Comment: hahaha that's right. I try to simulate on my head like you mentioned. thanks in advance

Comment: hope that will help you. Learn to use objects in the future  Will help you a lot. It will help you to organise your functions and variables. https://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials